# How to design ElasticSearch indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document storage with multiple types. Each document type has some basic metadata, like uuid, and a single "entity" field holding a stringified json with the actual content. This is because the document, event though it has a type, does not have a strict schema and any user can provide data in any structure.

I need to be able to browse, filter and search through these documents so I will be putting them into ElasticSearch.

My question is: how should I structure the ES? I have read that having too many indexes is not good for ES and that it is better to have as least indexes as possible. But ES also does not like if documents of the same type have different structure(mapping) + you cannot change mapping for existing fields, only append for new ones.

The "schema" is fixed for every document type and user so I could create new index for each user with the same type(s) in it but as I've mentioned, having lots of indexes is bad.

So what is the recommended design in such case?

This might sound crazy but would it be feasible to parse the document into key/value format where the key would be the property path? The only issues I see here is that everything would have to be set as fulltext which does not sound like a good idea.

Edit: seems like ES does this on its own https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html but I'm still not sure what to do.

Comment: Can you show a few sample relevant documents that you wish to store?

Comment: It's not about the documents themselves, its about the unpredictable schema and how to approach the indexing.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is to have an array of `nested` object types with a `key` and `value` fields, i.e. your mapping would look like

```
"entity": {
   "type": "nested",
   "properties": {
      "key": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

That way you can store pretty much anything you want in the `entity` field without risking a mapping type explosion, for instance

```
{
   "uuid": "",
   "entity": [
     {"key": "myfield1", "value": "Some value"},
     {"key": "myfield2", "value": "Some value"},
     {"key": "myfield3", "value": "Some value"}
   ]
}
```

Then you'll have to make sure to use `nested` queries when querying your data but it's definitely feasible.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have described in the question with the shortcoming being the fixed field type which is bad for filtering.

Comment: Why is that bad? with a bunch of nested queries you can achieve it. Can you show a sample query that you'd like to run?

Comment: Well, if all the values are fulltext then you cannot perform date/int/.. range query or anything like that(properly).

Comment: well, there's always a trade-off... as the saying goes, if you let garbage in, you get garbage out ;-) But I'm still interested to see a concrete piece of data you have and a query you'd like to perform on it.

Comment: There is no data. I'm currently designing the architecture. My use case is "product" objects. Each customer has his own "app" and each "app" has a "product" entity. Each "product" can have different "bundles" of fields - imagine product type. All "products" are stored in central SPOT repository as documents and I need to provide search and filtering for these documents.

Comment: why not having one index per product type then?

Comment: Because in ES docs it says ES does not like too many indexes. So let's say I have 100 apps with 10 product types = 1000 indexes.

Comment: It also depends on how you will query them. If not too many docs per index, you can have a single primary shard per index (+ replicas across nodes) and if your queries only span a single index, it doesn't hurt to have many indices. The only problem is when you have too many indices and your queries span all of them (via an alias)

Comment: The queries will be per app.